# $H_2(M)$ is free abelian for any simply connected $4$-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

In Naber's book *"Topology, Geometry and Gauge Fields. Foundations"*, it is stated that for each $4$-manifold $M$ which is smooth, closed, connected and simply connected we have $H_0(M) = H_4(M)= \mathbb Z$, $H_1(M)=H_3(M)=0$ and $H_2(M)$ is a finitely generated free abelian group. The statements about $H_k(M)$, $k\neq 2$ are clear for me. It is also clear that $H_2(M)$ is finitely generated (since there is a finite triangulation). But how to see that this group is also free?

Comment: Use the universal coefficients theorem and Poincaré duality.

Comment: @DanielRust could you give one more hint please? I used these to obtain statements about other homology groups but I don't see how to use it with $H_2$.

Comment: You know $H_2$ will be free abelian if and only if it is torsion free (because it is finitely generated). What does this tell you about the SES from the universal coefficient theorem?

Comment: Is there a nondegenerate pairing $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \to \mathbb Z$?

Comment: @John: any such pairing is zero.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the Universal coefficient theorem (for cohomology) and the assumption that $M$ is simply connected, we have $$H^2(M)=\operatorname{Hom}(H_2(M),\mathbb{Z})\oplus \operatorname{Ext}(H_1(M),\mathbb{Z})= \operatorname{Hom}(H_2(M),\mathbb{Z}),$$ which is torsion free, hence free abelian (because it is finitely generated). By Poincaré duality, $H^2(M)\cong H_2(M)$ and we're done.